# How to display parent child flat table records as nested list in Php?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a Laravel app. I have a self referencing table. I need to display the record as nested as shown below.

Here is the entries in the table :

```
id            name              parent
1             Task 1             0 
2             Task 2             0
3             Sub Task 1         1
4             Sub Task 2         1
5             Sub Task 3         2
6             Task 3             0
7             Sub Sub Task 1     4
```

The desired result is:

```
Task 1 
  Sub Task 1
  Sub Task 2 
    Sub Sub Task 1
 Task 2
  Sub Task 3
Taks 3
```

Would you please let me know how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please share what you have tried. FYI check [laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a self-referring relationship

```
class Task extends Model{

    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'parent');
    }
}
```

in your controller:

```
$tasks = Task::where('parent',0)->get();
return view ('tasks.index',compact('tasks'));
```

Then make the view recursive.

```
<div>
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        {{$task->name}}
        @if(count($task->tasks))
            @include('tasks.index',['tasks' => $task->tasks])
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

(might need some cleaning up to prevent confusing the variable names, but you get the general idea)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
class Task extends Model
{
    public function tasks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task', 'parent')
            ->with('tasks');
    }
}
```